# why I cannot get facebook Key hash but get 'YOR7'

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio, facebook-login

I want to get my release key hash for Facebook Android SDK.

I followed facebook getting started tutorial
paste following code to my cmd

```
 keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Users\USER\.android\debug.keystore | C:\openssl\bin\openssl sha1 -binary | C:\openssl\bin\openssl base64
```

got

```
Enter keystore password:
```

After I enter : android
it came out

```
YOR7

Warning:
The JKS keystore uses a proprietary format. It is recommended to migrate to PKCS12 which is an industry standard format using "keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore C:\Users\USER\.android\debug.keystore -destkeystore C:\Users\USER\.android\debug.keystore -deststoretype pkcs12".
```

without Key hash
How can I solve this problem ?

Thanks ~

Answer (score 0):

can u use this code to get key for Facebook or google.

```
private fun printHashKey() {
    try {
        //Facebook
        Log.i("AppLog", "key:" + FacebookSdk.getApplicationSignature(this))
       //google
        Log.i("AppLog", SignatureUtils.getOwnSignatureHash(this))
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.i("AppLog", "error:", e)
    }
}
```

Comment: it cannot define 'SignatureUtils' should I import something?

Comment: SignatureUtils for google u need it now I send to u @qiantext

Comment: this link for SignatureUtils 
https://gist.github.com/Ahmedbadereldin/aaeda0e19773bad22390fb0b614ac10d

Answer (score 0):

I find the method from Internet

```
try {  
    PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(  
            "your.pakege.name",  
            PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);  
    for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {  
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");  
        md.update(signature.toByteArray());  
        Log.d("MyKeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(  
                            md.digest(),  
                            Base64.DEFAULT));   
    }    
} catch (Exception e) {    
    Log.d("FacebookHashKeyError",e.toString());
}
```

it turns out my key hash!